# Losing form_state value after second submit (ajax)

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have an form that I send with ajax:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
     ...
    if($form_state->getValue('g_actualPartIndex') == NULL){
        $form_state->setValue('g_actualPartIndex', 0);
    }
    $form = $this->setHeader($form, $form_state);

     $form['Next'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => "Go to next step",
        '#ajax' => [
            'wrapper' => 'projekt-form-wrapper',
            'callback' => [$this, 'form_ajax_submit'],
            'method' => 'replace',
            'effect' => 'fade'
        ]
    );

    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="projekt-form-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    return $form;
}

public function form_ajax_submit($form, $form_state) {
    $form_state->setValue('g_actualPartIndex',
       (int)($form_state->getValue('g_actualPartIndex')) + 1);

    $form = $this->setHeader($form, $form_state);
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand(
        '#projekt-form-wrapper',
         $form
    ));
    return $response;
}
```

As you can see, in `buildForm` I set `g_actualPartIndex` to `0` if no value is set (we enter the form for the first time). Later, in ajax callback `form_ajax_submit` I increment the `g_actualPartIndex` by one and replace old form with the new one. My `setHeader(...)` method displays the actual step index:

```
private function setHeader(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $actualPartIndex = $form_state->getValue('g_actualPartIndex');
    $form['header'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => t('<div id="generatorHeader">
            <span class="part '.($actualPartIndex == 0 ? 'active' : '').'">Part 1</span>
            <span class="part '.($actualPartIndex == 1 ? 'active' : '').'">Part 2</span>
            <span class="part '.($actualPartIndex == 2 ? 'active' : '').'">Part 3</span>
            <span class="part '.($actualPartIndex == 3 ? 'active' : '').'">Part 4</span>
            <span class="part '.($actualPartIndex == 4 ? 'active' : '').'">Part 5</span>
            <span class="part '.($actualPartIndex == 5 ? 'active' : '').'">Part 6</span>
        </div>'),
    );

    return $form;
}
```

When I load the page, I see "Part 1" with class "active". When I click "Go to next step", the form is replaced by form with "Part 2" as "active". The problem is, when I click "Go to next step" again, the form reloads... and **I'm still in "Part 2" instead of "Part 3"**.

Is `form_state` losing it's value due to some rebuild or something? Or the error is somewhere else?